# Pueden decirme si existe otra manera de instalar whisper para usar en python, que no sea desde el repositorio de github?

Tags: python, github

```
(env) E:\Programacion\PROYECTOS>pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
  Cloning https://github.com/openai/whisper.git to c:\users\marcos\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-2g1yrlbs
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-2g1yrlbs'
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/openai/whisper.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8087: Connection refused
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-2g1yrlbs' did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 128
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-2g1yrlbs' did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 128
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: No hay, tienes que clonarlo. Lo raro es que te sale `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8087: Connection refused` al intentar acceder a github; suena a que tienes algo quemado en el hosts o algún proxy por ahí

Comment: ¿Has resuelto todas las dependencias que se indican; ffmpeg, rust y setuptools-rust? También [dice](https://github.com/openai/whisper#setup) que es seguro que ejecute en Python 3.8 a 3.10, verifica que tengas alguna versión de esas. Adicional, según la documentación usa Pytorch y, no se si me equivoco, tiene mejor soporte en GPUs NVidia. Verificar si esto será un problema en tu configuración de hardware.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, revisaré las dependencias aunque ya tengo ffmpeg instalada.